# What is ArcGIS Marketplace?

Tags: arcgis-market-place

Does any one know (OR using OR have experience) exactly what is [ArcGIS Marketplace](http://marketplace.arcgis.com/)?

According to Google search its related with selling apps and GIS data built using ESRI software's.

Is there any additional information/help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the name suggests, the ArcGIS Marketplace is a new portal for ESRI's Users, where they can purchase access to Data and Apps based upon the ArcGIS Online platform.

As the [FAQ](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/marketplace/consumer/faq.htm) mentions:

> ***What is ArcGIS Marketplace and what does it mean to me?***
>
> ArcGIS Marketplace provides your organization a way to discover and
>   access apps and data to use within the ArcGIS platform. ArcGIS
>   Marketplace is your one stop for apps and data from authorized Esri
>   Business Partners, Esri Distributors, and Esri. Apps and data in
>   ArcGIS Marketplace are built to leverage and enhance what your
>   organization can do with ArcGIS Online. ArcGIS Marketplace includes
>   both paid and free apps and many apps have free trials.