# Seeking marketplace intended to commercialize QGIS applications?

Tags: qgis-plugins, web-mapping, commercial

If we want to sell general application such as website theme, plugins, mobile app, game, etc, we can use envato marketplace, google play store, or other marketplaces for selling and buying application.

However, i need to knows if there is a marketplace that functioning to sell and buy application in the realm of GIS such as Webgis template, QGIS plugin, or standalone application used for geospatial needs, etc?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking a QGIS question about plugging a gap compared to the Esri offering mentioned at http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/72988/115

Comment: Possibly related: http://blog.qgis.org/2016/04/23/promoting-and-using-qgis-for-the-enterprise/

Comment: Let me clarify my question with a specific case. (1) if i have a web template, i can sell it on envato marketplaces such as themeforest, but if i have webmap template, where i have to sell? (2) If i have a general program, i can sell it at codecanyon, but if i have GIS application, where i have to sell? Is there any marketplace that intended to GIS needs...?

Comment: To clarify a question please use the [edit] button beneath it but remember that there should be only one question per question as per the [Tour].